# Guaranteeing Service starts first upon reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a service inside an app: `serviceA`.  I want to insure that `serviceA` is the *first service to run at boot* (after the system services, of course).

I currently have implemented all the necessary intent-filters: `BOOT_COMPLETED`, `QUICKBOOT_POWERON`, `PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, and `REBOOT`.  (From reading I know that `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` and `PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED` are redundant, but I keep them to make me happy).

However, my service is not the first.  I'm assuming that there is no real way to deterministically guarantee that my application's service is the first one to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming that there is no real way to deterministically guarantee that my application's service is the first one to start.

You could build your own custom ROM. Then, you could tinker with how Android handles the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast and arrange to get it first yourself. Or, you could dump Android services entirely and do whatever it is that your are doing via a Linux daemon.

Otherwise, no, as `BOOT_COMPLETED` is not an ordered broadcast.

Comment: That's what I was 100% certain of but wanted to make sure I didn't miss any other means of doing so.  Thanks!